# Sampling of Species counting same member of species twice

Tags: population-dynamics, population-biology

As part of the biology class, we performed a sample on the number of red squirrels in a forest a few miles away from the classroom to estimate its population.

When we returned to analyse our data, we were discussing about the validity of our sample, and I was wondering whether the idea that the same member of the species being sampled twice may have an effect.

The book I was reading stated:

> a sampling procedure does not have to uniquely identify each member of a population to gain an idea of relative numbers.

I'm slightly confused as to why sampling the same member of the species twice **is not** something that affects the validity of our final estimate for population size.

Can someone explain why the passage in the book is correct?

Comment: Can you please explain exactly how you estimate the population size. Do you do some capture-marking-recapture or some other method? Do you take any genetic data?

Comment: Note that the quote says, "relative numbers." This means that you would need to use the same sampling procedure for each sample (true but not necessarily obvious). Then when comparing samples one would expect that different samples would have similar numbers  of species being sampled twice.

In other words, as long as each sample is obtained in the same manner, one would generally expect that the same sampling errors would be replicated in each sample, and therefore would still allow one to gain "an idea of relative numbers."